# Derive conditional density of a random variable?

Tags: probability

If you have a random variable $X$ that is distributed exponentially with the parameter $\lambda$, how do you condition it on a constant?

For example, $E[X\mid X>y]$. I am confused because $y$ seems completely irrelevant to this distribution. Can we condition on $y$?

Comment: Is $y$ a variable or a constant? You claim that it is a variable, but lower case letters are usually constant. And this example highly suggests that it is a constant.

Comment: I guess it's a constant. The problem doesn't specify, but you're right, the notation makes it seem like a constant. Assuming it is a constant, can you explain what to do?

Comment: The presentation highly suggests that it is a constant. Take instead $X$ that follows uniform distribution on (0,1). It makes sense to ask if $X>1/2$, what is the expected value of $X$. In other words, $E[X|X>1/2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can condition on the event $X\gt y$. For example, we can ask what is the expected value of $X$, given that $X\gt 1.5$.

Fix $y\gt 0$. Given that $X\gt y$, we calculate the probability that $X\le w$. This is clearly $0$ if $w\le y$. So let $w\gt y$. We have 
$$\Pr(X\le w\mid X\gt y)=\frac{\Pr(X\le w\cap X\gt y)}{\Pr(X\gt y)}.$$
Compute. The numerator is $(1-e^{-\lambda w})-(1-e^{-\lambda y})$, and the denominator is $e^{-\lambda y}$. So the conditional cdf of $X$ given $X\gt y$ is $1-e^{-\lambda(w-y)}$. We could have obtained this result more simply by referring to the *memorylessness* property of the exponential.

Thus the conditional density of $X$, given that $Y\gt y$, is $\lambda e^{-\lambda(w-y)}$ (for $w\gt y$). Now we can find the conditional expectation by integrating as usual.

Comment: So if I'm being asked for the conditional density of $X$ given that $X>y$, I can calculate it as $P[X=x|X>y]=\frac{P[X=x \cap X>y]}{P[X>y]}$?

Comment: I do not like the notation, since $\Pr(X=x)$, conditional or not, is $0$. But the conditional density can indeed be computed directly, without going through the cdf. I went through the cdf for the sake of logical  clarity.

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean on the density. Would you mind showing me how? My inclination is to do it the way I've noted, but I agree that that's not right.

Answer (score 0):

Only one **random variable** is involved and that is $X$.  There is a tacit universal quantifier, as in "For all values of $y\ge 0$, $\operatorname{E}(X\mid X>y) = \cdots\cdots$".  Thus if $y=6$, you have $$\operatorname{E}(X\mid X>6) = \text{some quantity}$$ and if $y=8$ you have $$\operatorname{E}(X\mid X>8) = \text{some other quantity found by putting 8 where 6 appeared earlier}$$ and in general $$\operatorname{E}(X\mid X>y) = \text{some other quantity found by putting $y$ where 6 or 8 appeared earlier}.$$

It is somewhat conventional, but not universal, to use capital letters near the end of the alphabet to refer to random variables, and lower-case letters as bound variables.  That makes it possible to understand things like $\Pr(X>x)$ and things like the difference between $f_X(3.6)$ and $f_Y(3.6)$, where (capital) $X$ and (capital) $Y$ are random variables.

Comment: Okay, I follow that. But I don't see how to express this mathematically. For instance, I am supposed to find the conditional density of $X$ given that $X>y$. Since $X$ is exponentially distributed, I have that the density of $X$ is $\frac{1}{\lambda}e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}}$. But I don't know what to do with this condition.

Comment: You use the condition to find the normalizing constant and also to complete the piecewise definition. It is not correct to say that the density initially is $(1/\lambda) e^{-x/\lambda}$ without adding that it is equal to that for $x>0$ and is equal to $0$ for $x<0$.  Similarly, given the condition $X>y$, you need to say that the density as a function of (lower-case) $x$ is equal to one expression for $x>y$ and another for $x<y$.  You also need to multiply it by a normalizing constant found by integrating from $y$ to $\infty$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing expectation conditioned on another random variable, $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$, and expectation conditioned on an event, $\mathsf E(X\mid X\in A)$, because, yeah, they do look pretty similar.

However, $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$ is a random variable measured against the sigma algebra generated by $Y$, while $\mathsf E(X\mid X\in A)$ is a value.   In this case:

$$\mathsf E(X\mid X>y) = \frac{\int\limits_{\max(y,0)}^\infty x~\lambda~\mathsf e^{-\lambda x}\operatorname d x}{\int\limits_{\max(y,0)}^\infty \lambda~\mathsf e^{-\lambda x}\operatorname d x} = {\max(y,0)}+\tfrac 1 \lambda$$

Which introduces *the memoryless property* of the *exponential distribution*.

$$\mathsf E(X\mid X>y) = y+\mathsf E(X) \qquad \textsf{if }X\sim\mathcal {Exp}(\lambda), y>0$$

Comment: "random variable measured against (a) sigma algebra" ?? What does that mean?